# On a road that comes to a stop sign, and then veers slightly to the right, do you need to use a turn signal to stay to the right?

Tags: driving, pennsylvania

Please note there is no other way to go legally except to the right. This road has a triangle that you have an option to make a left turn before it if that was the direction you wanted to go. Once passed that (about another 50-60 feel ahead) there is the stop sign and the road curves to the right. After stopping, I was given a ticket for continuing onto the road without signaling. I've lived in the area 30+ years and have never signaled there, and anyone I've asked agrees. 
 Travelling from the south to north, stopping at the stop sign then continuearound that curve... would a signal be legally needed?
See my very crude sample... also the distance between where you could go left, and the stop sign is only about 3-4 car lengths in real life. 
 TIA.[image]

Comment: I'm with you on this one. If there's only one legal option then signalling isn't necessary.

Comment: You've never seen anyone make a left from the stop sign because they missed the earlier turn? Or is a left turn at that location blocked by a median or curb?

Comment: What country/state is this in?

Comment: I don't know which legislation this happened in, but how do you expect other drivers coming from the top of your map and driving 'downwards', who are unfamiliar with the crossing and traffic pattern, to know that you are going to turn right, without you using your turn signal? I checked the regulations of the country I am living in, and at least here, just as I expected, you are obligated to use your turn signal if you are turning, even if turning in one direction is the only option you have.

Comment: Please provide the exact address of the road to prevent us from guessing. Closing until then.

Comment: @brhans I don't think you can state that as a universal rule. For example, the California Driver Handbook says "Always use your turn signals.", and I cannot find any exception for the case where the turn is legally required.